# "Unresolved import" for Python package installed using setup.py

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I'm receiving a "[Python] Unresolved import.." error for a custom package that I have installed with `python setup.py install`. If I instead install the package with `pip` by running `python setup.py sdist` and then running `pip install <package.tar.gz>` the error goes away, and I cannot figure out why. I am running all of this within the same virtualenv, and I have made sure that VS Code is correctly using this virtualenv as the source interpreter (this is Python 3.7). Although I could find a workaround here, `pip install` is not always available. Any thoughts?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Can you still import the module manually when you use `python setup.py install`? If so then please consider filing a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server .